# Ansible vsphere_guest module reports "Could not clone selected machine: [Task Error]: The operation is not supported on the object."

Tags: vmware, ansible, vsphere

Here is my play -

```
 tasks:
  - name: Deploy an instance
    vsphere_guest:
        vcenter_hostname: 10.171.52.38
        username: testuser
        password: test
        guest: newvm001
        from_template: yes
        template_src: Ubuntu 14.04
        power_on_after_clone: No
        resource_pool: "/Resources"
        validate_certs: no
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the VMware community , “To be able clone a virtual machine, you must be connected to vCenter Server. You cannot clone virtual machines if you connect directly to an ESXi host”
SO we will require vCenter access to clone this it seems.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to do this using the ESXi host. It works now.